# Providing MVC Shared Folder Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a project and I would like to be able to place a number of views within the shared folder.  However when these are all created (through a generation process) i begin to feel "custer&^%$ fobic" due to having  X * N partial views within the shared folder and am looking for a better organizational model.

Is it possible to just create a folder structure in the Shared folders and "Hope" MVC wires them up correctly or do I have to do something else.

Ex.
Folder structure I have

```
...
Shared
    Product1DropdownList.ascx
    Product2DropdownList.ascx
    Product3DropdownList.ascx
    Product1Search.ascx
    Product2Search.ascx
    Product3Search.ascx
...


Folder Structure I would like
...
Shared
    Product
        Product1DropdownList.ascx
        Product1Search.ascx
    Product2
        Product2DropdownList.ascx
        Product2Search.ascx
    Product3
        Product3DropdownList.ascx
        Product3Search.ascx
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for a simple ViewEngine over-ride.

In your derived ViewEngine, you can set rules, subdirectorties to search etc etc to instruct MVC how to find the view .....

There are quite a few examples of this approach around the web, but no "definitive" code since the usage can be quite dynamic, but I suggest you refer to:

[Chris Pietschmann:Implement Theme Folders using a Custom ViewEngine](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/26/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx)

for ideas and inspiration.

Comment: Cool will play with that... Figured there was a way to do it because of the Object Templates just didn't know where to start.